# If user is not authenticated go to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net

task: If user is not authenticated go to login page!

I want this behavior in every action of every controller.

But offcourse I do not want to have logic in every action for this

```
if (User == null || User.Identity == null || !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Authentication");
}
```

What is good practive for this?

---

I added to web config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Authentication" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

Controllers have attribute [authorize], except AuthenticationController where I have[AllowAnonymous]

But still not redirect to login page (just show error: HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized)

---

Edit2:
Solved!

I had

```
 <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
```

in web.cofig

When I remove this line everything was fine

Comment: Perhaps the [`[Authorize]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) would be of use to you.

Comment: with authorize atribure i get 401, which is good. But I also need redirect to login page. Where to define what page is login page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should define membership provider or something provides Identity for your system. Then you should use Authorize attribute for your controller.

Authorize attiribute redirects action to login view if user is not authenticated.

Comment: with authorize atribure i get 401, which is good. But I also need redirect to login page. Where to define what page is login page?

Comment: SOLVED: I just remove ' <remove name="FormsAuthentication" /> ' from web.cofig file